# Finding rows in numpy array with specific condition efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have two numpy array 2D. What I want to do is to find specific rows of `np_weight` in the `np_sentence`.

For example:

```
#rows are features, columns are clusters or whatever
np_weight = np.random.uniform(1.0,10.0,size=(7,4))
print(np_weight)

[[9.96859395 8.65543961 6.07429382 4.58735497]
 [3.21776471 8.33560037 2.11424961 8.89739975]
 [9.74560314 5.94640798 6.10318198 7.33056421]
 [6.60986206 2.36877835 3.06143215 7.82384351]
 [9.49702267 9.98664568 3.89140374 5.42108704]
 [1.93551346 8.45768507 8.60233715 8.09610975]
 [5.21892795 4.18786508 5.82665674 8.28397111]]

#rows are sentence index, columns are words on that sentence
np_sentence = np.random.randint(0.0,7.0,size=(5,3))
print(np_sentence)

[[2 5 1]
 [1 6 4]
 [0 0 0]
 [2 3 6]
 [4 2 4]]
```

If I sort `np_weight` on each column and then get top5 of that, I will have this one
**(here I just show the first column)**:

```
temp_sorted_result=
[9.96859395 ] --->index=0
[9.74560314 ] --→ index=2
[9.49702267 ] --→ index=4
[6.60986206 ] --->index=3
[5.21892795 ] --->index=6
```

Now, I want to search these indexes two by two in the second numpy array `np_sentence` to see is there any row on that which contains two of the indexes.

For example, based on this it has to output: `1,3,4`. These are the indices of the `np_sentence` which includes a combination of two of the indexes in `temp_sorted_result`.

for instance, `both 4 and 6` which are available in `temp_sorted_result`  are in the same row of `np_sentence` in the `row=1` and so on.

I need to do this for each column of `np_weight`. It is very important for me to have a very efficient code as the number of the rows are very large

What I have done so far is only searching one item in the second array which is not what I want ultimately:

One approach could be I form all the combinations for each column, for example for the first column showed above `temp_sorted_result`, I form

```
(0,2) (0,4)(0,3) (0,6)
(2,4) (2,3) (2,6)
(4,3)(4,6)
(3,6)
```

and then check which one is available in the rows of `np_sentence`. Base on my `np_sentence` rows index of `1,3,4` contains some of these.

Now my question is that how can I implement this in a most efficient way?

Please let me know if it is not obvious.

I appreciate your help:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach: The function `f` below creates a mask the same shape as `weight` (plus one dummy row of `False`s) marking the top five entries in each column with `True`.

It then uses `np_sentence` to index into the mask and counts the `True` for each column,row pair and compares with the threshold two.

Only complication: We must suppress duplicate values in rows of `np_sentence`. To that end we sort the rows and then direct each index which equals its left neighbor to the dummy row in the mask.

This function returns a mask. The last line of the script demonstrates how to convert that mask to indices.

```
import numpy as np

def f(a1, a2, n_top, n_hit):
    N,M = a1.shape
    mask = np.zeros((N+1,M), dtype=bool)
    np.greater_equal(
        a1,a1[a1.argpartition(N-n_top, axis=0)[N-n_top], np.arange(M)],
        out=mask[:N])
    a2 = np.sort(a2, axis=1)
    a2[:,1:][a2[:,1:]==a2[:,:-1]] = N
    return np.count_nonzero(mask[a2], axis=1) >= n_hit

a1 = np.matrix("""[[9.96859395 8.65543961 6.07429382 4.58735497]
 [3.21776471 8.33560037 2.11424961 8.89739975]
 [9.74560314 5.94640798 6.10318198 7.33056421]
 [6.60986206 2.36877835 3.06143215 7.82384351]
 [9.49702267 9.98664568 3.89140374 5.42108704]
 [1.93551346 8.45768507 8.60233715 8.09610975]
 [5.21892795 4.18786508 5.82665674 8.28397111]]"""[2:-2].replace("]\n [",";")).A

a2 = np.matrix("""[[2 5 1]
 [1 6 4]
 [0 0 0]
 [2 3 6]
 [4 2 4]]"""[2:-2].replace("]\n [",";")).A

print(f(a1,a2,5,2))

from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

print([[*map(itemgetter(1),grp)] for k,grp in groupby(np.argwhere(f(a1,a2,5,2).T),itemgetter(0))])
```

Output:

```
[[False  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True]
 [False False False False]
 [ True False  True  True]
 [ True  True  True False]]
[[1, 3, 4], [0, 1, 4], [0, 1, 3, 4], [0, 1, 3]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for putting effort and sharing ur idea with me, that is awesome. I need to check it on the real data which I might have 800K rows. I will ask you question if I faced with something. Again Many thanks, this is wonderfull.

Comment: Thanks again, Now I checked it, I was wondering is there any way I can have the index of the np_weight rather the other matrice? All the things are the way I want except I also need the index of the first matrix which has been repeated two by two in the first matrix itself.

Comment: I have updated my question with minor modification. Sorry if Im asking you to help with the modification, I truly appreciate your help.

Comment: I understand it is too much question in one stack question, but as they are closely related Im not sure it will be good idea starting new question. I want to keep your approach for doing it in most effiecient way. please let me know if you want me to start a new question for the update I made, Thank you again.

Comment: @sariii just make a new question and link this one. I may not be able to answer immediately, but maybe some one else does.

Comment: Panzar Sure, I will do. I think it makes more sense creating new question as it too much for one question. Again thank you.

Comment: Actually, I break down the question. Im done with top positive negative idea and create the final array including keeping all the values I need. but in final step I need to apply the idea of keeping the values having a combination of two, I simply could not come up with an idea. even following your answer and I kind of understanding what you have done, but now that I need to change the matrix to the original matrix I can not get the same result. can you please have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56532577/filter-tensorflow-array-with-specific-condition-over-numpy-array

Comment: Actually Im not able to do this mask[a2] with regard to the fact that i need the original matrix. Sorry for commenting here, I feel this is a difficult task and I may not find anybody able to solve it!. anyway this is my last comment here. sorry again for bothering.